# Running R function jags on cluster

Tags: r, pbs, r2jags

I am trying to run a R program on cluster. In the R program,`jags` function is called from the package `R2jags`. If I don't use the cluster and simply use R, then the program works fine. However, when I try to submit a job, then I get the following error. If I don't call the function `jags` and use the cluster then it works just fine.

```
Loading required package: rjags
Loading required package: coda
Linked to JAGS 4.0.0
Loaded modules: basemod,bugs

Attaching package: ‘R2jags’

The following object is masked from ‘package:coda’:

    traceplot


 *** caught illegal operation ***
address 0x7fe566be8917, cause 'illegal operand'

Traceback:
 1: dyn.load(file)
 2: load.module(jags.module[m])
 3: jags(model.file = "myfile.txt", data = model.data,     inits = model.initial.values, parameters = model.parameters,     n.chains = 1, n.iter = 500, n.burnin = 5, n.thin = 5)
An irrecoverable exception occurred. R is aborting now ...
 line 15: 34161 Illegal instruction     (core dumped) Rscript test1.R
```

Comment: Your chances of getting an answer will greatly increase if you provide a simple, self-contained example of your problem. This would include toy input data, your code, any error messages, and expected output. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) may be helpful.

Comment: @Limey Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66126166/error-while-running-r-code-after-submitting-a-job. I have posted a similar question with an example.