# Error while running R code after submitting a job

Tags: r, parallel.foreach, pbs, torque, rjags

If I simply run the R code then it works. However, it does not work when I submit a job.

I am trying to run `myRcode.R` file by submitting a job. Following is the `.sh` file:

```
#!/bin/bash
#PBS -N myRexample # Set job name to myjob
#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=2 # Request 1 node with 2 processors
#PBS -l mem=8gb # Request 8gb memory
#PBS -l walltime=1:00:00 # Request 1hr job time
#PBS -V # Use submission environment
cd "$PBS_O_WORKDIR"
Rscript myRcode.R
```

Following is my R code (`myRcode.R`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript
#Call the required functions and library
source("function1.R") 
library(R2jags)

#Function to be used in parallel computation  
mysim <- function(sim_number){
  set.seed(sim_number)
  outs <- function1() #rjags is called inside function1.
    return(list(outs[[1]],outs[[2]]))
}
 
#Parallel Computation
library(parallel)
library(doParallel)
registerDoParallel(cl <- parallel::makeCluster(2,outfile="test.txt"));

    results <- foreach(x = 1:2,
                        .packages = c('MASS','R2jags'))%dopar% { mysim(sim_number=x)} 
  stopCluster(cl)
```

Following is the error that I am getting:

```
Loading required package: rjags
Loading required package: coda
Linked to JAGS 4.0.0
Loaded modules: basemod,bugs

Attaching package: ‘R2jags’

The following object is masked from ‘package:coda’:

    traceplot

Loading required package: foreach
Loading required package: iterators
Error in unserialize(socklist[[n]]) : error reading from connection
Calls: %dopar% ... recvOneData -> recvOneData.SOCKcluster -> unserialize
Execution halted
```

Following is the `test.txt` file:

```
starting worker pid=59438 on localhost:11788 at 08:55:04.422
starting worker pid=59451 on localhost:11788 at 08:55:04.799
Loading required package: rjags
Loading required package: rjags
Loading required package: coda
Loading required package: coda
Linked to JAGS 4.0.0
Loaded modules: basemod,bugs
Linked to JAGS 4.0.0
Loaded modules: basemod,bugs

Attaching package: ‘R2jags’


Attaching package: ‘R2jags’

The following object is masked from ‘package:coda’:

    traceplot

The following object is masked from ‘package:coda’:

    traceplot


 *** caught illegal operation ***
address 0x7f51ceed1917, cause 'illegal operand'

 *** caught illegal operation ***
address 0x7fe45c73d917, cause 'illegal operand'
```

Comment: Write test code that doesn't do anything other than check for the availability of each package on each node of the cluster and then attempts to load it.  That will help identify which one is causing the problem.  My suspicion is that one (or both) of them is/are not available to your batch job.  Given that you are batching, details of your OS would be helpful.  Also check that `$PBS_O_WORKDIR` is defined correctly at the the working directory is set as you expect.

Comment: @Limey Firstly, thanks for the response. If I go to the terminal and run my R code by `Rscript myRcode.R` then it works just fine. I also checked for the availability of each package on each node of the cluster then it works fine by using `qsub myscript.sh`.

Comment: @Limey I added `registerDoParallel(cl <- parallel::makeCluster(2,outfile="test.txt"))`. When I submit a job, I get the following on `test.txt` file.

Comment: @Limey Please see the question above as I have added portion of `test.txt`.

Comment: Thank you, that's helpful.  But unfortunately the uncontrolled nature of the error means that I'm out of ideas and suggests that cause is a bug.  Or at least an unanticipated situation.  I can't suggest anything more than raising an issue with the autors of the package(s).

Comment: @Limey Thanks. I also think the issue is with the `R2jags` package when trying to run in the cluster.